# Android Studio code writing a local file on OSX

Tags: java, android, macos

Running in the Debug mode, with phone connected "not emulator", this Android Studio code tries to create/write a file on the local Mac machine running El Capitan but it gives error:

> java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
                try {
                  Log.d("TAG", "trying to write to file");
                  String path = "/Users/myName/Desktop/sss.html";
                  File file = new File(path);
                  // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                  if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                  }
                  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                  // write in file
                  bw.write(response);
                  // close connection
                  bw.close();
                  Log.d("TAG", "finish file writing");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                }
```

I don't know how to create a file on the local developing machine and would appreciate some how to. Thanks

**edit**
As stated in the comments. If the path is pointing to a file on the phone, How can I adjust it so that it points to a file on the developing machine?

Comment: consider this: what do you expect would happen in you run this on an android phone instead of an emulator?

Comment: @njzk2 I am not sure if the code is trying to create the file in the phone or in  the developing machine and would appreciate a hand or two. ;) And if it points to the phone, how can I adjust the path to point to the development machine?

Comment: You can't. It's a different machine altogether. It would be like writing to the machine of your colleague who seats next to you. You'd need some form or another of network communication between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make or write to a file from a phone/emulator on a devoloping machine without some form of network.

These are 2 different machines and are completely independent.

You can always make a file on the emulator and send it to your developing machine using some kind of network.